# Thread doesn't run like I say it should with GPIOs in Python on RPi

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, gpio

I am creating a script on my raspberry pi that if you press a button the led on the button need to be flashing till I press the button again. 
This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import threading
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pushbutton = 2
led = 3
GPIO.setup(pushbutton, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)

class rpiThread(threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self):
                self.running = False
                super(rpiThread, self).__init__()
        def start(self):
                self.running = True
                super(rpiThread, self).start()
        def run(self):
                self.running = True
                while (self.running == True):
                        GPIO.output(led, GPIO.HIGH)
                        print "HIGH"
                        sleep(0.05)
                        GPIO.output(led,GPIO.LOW)
                        print "LOW"
                        sleep(0.05)
        def stop(self):
                self.running = False
                GPIO.output(led, GPIO.LOW)

def main():
        myrpiThread = rpiThread()
        pushed = GPIO.input(pushbutton)
        try:
                while(True):
                        if(pushed == False):
                                if(GPIO.input(pushbutton) == False):
                                        sleep(0.5)
                                        if(GPIO.input(pushbutton) == False):
                                                myrpiThread.start()
                                                pushed = True
                                                print "The button is pushed"
                        else:
                                if(GPIO.input(pushbutton) == True):
                                        GPIO.output(led, GPIO.LOW)
                                        myrpiThread.stop()
                                        pushed = False
                                        print "The button is not pushed"
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print "QUIT"
main()
```

Always when I run my script my leds arn't flashing each 0.05 sec. Sometimes it takes 2 seconds before it turns on and sometime it just doesn't flash.
I dont know what I am doing wrong? Can someone please help me to figure out what the problem is?

Is it possible that GPIO pins are not made to use in multithreading?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial when I needed to use threaded callbacks with GPIO:
[how to use interrupts with python on the raspberry pi and rpi gpio](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio-part-2). It also has a good discussion in the comments about how to avoid using global variables to pass a value back from the threads.

It would be helpful to know exactly how you have your button wired, and what type of button you are using so that I could answer your problem more specifically.

I wrote the following example code assuming that you have the button wired from GPIO 2 to +3.3v
If you have it wired to ground use "pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN" and "GPIO.FALLING"
It also assumes you have a momentary push button. When the button push is detected it flips a global boolean value. That value is checked in the main loop, and the blink(led) function is called if pushed = True.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pushbutton = 2
led = 3
GPIO.setup(pushbutton, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(led, GPIO.OUT)
pushed = False

# this will run in another thread when the button is pushed 
def button_callback(channel):  
    pushed = not pushed

GPIO.add_event_detect(pushbutton, GPIO.RISING, callback=button_callback)

while True:
    if pushed:
        blink(led)

def blink(led):
    GPIO.output(led, True)
    sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(led, False)
```

I don't have a raspberry Pi in front of me right now to test this code, but I will check it later. You may have to modify this for your specific set up, but hopefully it gets you in the right direction.